# Pure Mathematics proof for $(-a)b$ =$-(ab)$

Tags: number-theory

How can I prove this without using the Multiplicative Property of zero? $(a*0=0)$

Comment: Hint :Use Peano's Axioms - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms

Comment: What is the algebraic structure we are working with here? Are these real numbers? Are they elements of a field or ring?

Comment: They are integers. And the only axioms allowed are closure, identity, associative, commutative, and distribution.

Comment: The multiplicative property of zero isn't an axiom but is in fact derivable from the axioms. Are you sure that you aren't allowed to prove that first?

Answer (score 14):

$$\begin{array}{rll}
(-a)b 
&= (-a)b + 0 &0 \text{ is identity for addition}\\
&= (-a)b + (ab + (-ab))&-ab \text{ is additive inverse of } ab\\
&= ((-a)b+ab) + (-ab)&\text{addition is associative}\\
&= ((-a+a)b) + (-ab)&\text{multiplication is distributive}\\
&= \color{blue}{(0b)} + (-ab)&-a \text{ is additive inverse of } a\\
&= \color{blue}{(0b + 0)} + (-ab)&0 \text{ is identity for addition}\\
&= \color{blue}{(0b + (0b + (-0b)))} + (-ab)& -0b \text{ is addition inverse of } 0b\\
&= \color{blue}{((0b + 0b) + (-0b))} + (-ab)& \text{addition is associative}\\
&= \color{blue}{((0+0)b + (-0b))} + (-ab)&\text{multiplication is distributive}\\
&= \color{blue}{(0b + (-0b))} + (-ab)&0 \text{ is identity for addition}\\
&= \color{blue}{0} + (-ab)&-0b \text{ is additive inverse of } 0b\\
&= -ab &0 \text{ is identity for addition}
\end{array}$$

Please note that the part in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ is a sub-proof of the statement $0b = 0$.

Comment: +1, this seems to be the first post that completely answers the question without assuming that 0b = 0.

Comment: I love this! This is basically the proof of 0a=0 hidden within this other proof.

Comment: @SebastianGarrido that's right. I have now colored that part in blue and hopefully this make everyone easier to see.

Comment: @DanielV: I did not assume $0b=0$.

Comment: Alternately to show $0b=0$ from ring axioms write $b=(0+1)b=0b+b$.

Comment: Interestingly, doesn't use multiplicative assoc, any commutivity, or multiplicative identity, making this a very general proof.  If you used the assumption that $f(f^{-1}(x))$ = $x$ and that addition and subtraction are inverses, I think you can get away without even using additive association.

Comment: Love this. Actually surprisingly effective and definitely smarter then whatever I could have thought of

Answer (score 2):

$-a = (-1)\cdot a$,
and you have LHS $= \big((-1)\cdot a \big)\cdot b = (-1)\cdot (a \cdot b)$ by associative property = RHS

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. I just wasn't sure if I was allowed to  do that.

Comment: Can we show $-a=(-1)\cdot a$ without using $a\cdot0=0$?

Answer (score 1):

We have that $a+(-a)=0$

$\implies b(a+(-a))=0\cdot b$

$\implies ba+b(-a)=0$

$\implies b(-a)=-(ba)$

Comment: you can use \cdot to make a $\cdot$ for multiplication between the $0$ and the $b$.

Comment: Thank you for the adivice, already edited. I'm relatively knew to LaTex

Comment: You make the assumption that $0 \cdot b$ = $b$, which is what the poster asked to not assume.

Answer (score 0):

In process of rewriting. Will be back soon.

Comment: Are you sure this won't use the property $0\cdot b=0$?

Comment: Ah, you use unfair tricks like actually reading the question carefully. Let me rewrite, or delete.

Comment: @anon: I think I patched it up. Please see the edit.

Comment: You are still assuming $0 \cdot b = 0$.

Comment: Actually, I'm not assuming it; I proved it: $0=0+0$, so$(0*b)=(0+0)b=0*b+0*b$. Then, from $0*b+0*b=0*b$ , I showed $0*b=0$.

Comment: So, here we go again: what's wrong with the post?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we only assume structure properties of distribution, closure, and existance/uniqueness of additive inverse.

$$(\forall a,b,c)\, (a + b)c = ac + bc\tag {R1}$$
Choose $b = -a$.
$$(\forall a,c)\, 0 \cdot c = ac + (-a)c \tag{R2}$$

Now let's consider the possibility that both are true:
$$(\exists x)\, 0\cdot x \ne 0 \tag{P1}$$ 
$$(\forall y,z)\, (-y)z = -(yz) \tag{P2}$$

Apply (P1) to (R2):
$$(\exists x \forall a)\, 0 \ne ax + (-a)x$$
Apply (P2):
$$(\exists x \forall a)\, 0 \ne ax + -(ax)$$

Which clearly contradicts closure and existance of an inverse.  So for this limited structure, $\lnot (P1) \lor \lnot (P2)$.

Answer (score 0):

by Munna shigri

a(-b)=-(ab)

proof:

0=0

b+(-b)=0.   {b+(-b)=0}

a{b+(-b)}=a0.      {multiplying by (a )on both side}

ab+a(-b)=a0.       {by distributive property}

ab+a(-b)=0.         {a0=0}

{ab+a(-b)}+(-(ab)=0+(-ab). { by adding (-ab) on both side}

{a(-b)+ab}+(-ab)=(-ab)+0.    {by comutative property}

a(-b)+{ab+(-ab)}=(-ab)+0.    {by associative property}

a(-b)+0=(-ab)+0.                    {a+(-a)=0}

a(-b)=-ab.     proved                             {a+0=a}

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) formatting.